# If pagestyle equal to... -- How should I ask it?

Tags: conditionals, header-footer

I'd like to use (or define) an If-statement for pagestyle.

I have no idea :(

Update:

 I'm using in my document about 4 pagestyles. Just as a little example I wish to have at the border of my document informations about jobname, date, time, lastsheet and sheetsequence AND size of the actual page. The size of the actual page is not everytime the same. That is why I thought, if I could define easy an if statement, it could be a great solution.

What I mean:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{pagestyle}{numberone}}{size: $210 \times 297 $}{size: $420 \times 297$}
```

I hope it is clear now

Comment: Looking at the definition of `\pagestyle` reveals that the page style isn't stored explicitly. The `\thispagestyle` stores its argument in `\@specialstyle`, but this isn't very useful in general. Maybe if you are telling us what exactly you want to achieve we might be better able to help you. Every page style is defined by a `\ps@<style>` macro, e.g. `\ps@plain` for `plain`. Depending on your application you could add code to these macros instead of detecting the style.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us a little more about what you want to achieve? To my admittedly old blinkered way of thinking, "the document commands the pagestyle", yet you are asking that "the pagestyle commands the document". Some of us may find that a bit of a strange new idea; I'm sure we'd all like to understand it better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can patch the page style declarations `\pagestyle` and `\thispagestyle` to record the page style in a macro.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\pagestyle}{%
  \gdef\@regularpagestyle{#1}%
  \gdef\thepagestyle{\if@specialpage\@specialstyle\else\@regularpagestyle\fi}
  }
{\message{(patching of \string\pagestyle\ succeeded)}}
{\message{(patching of \string\pagestyle\ failed)}}
\makeatother

%\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}

%\thepagestyle

\lipsum

\ifdef{\thepagestyle}{
  The page style is `\thepagestyle'.%
}{%
  There is no page style declared.
}

\end{document}
```

The commands `\pretocmd` and `\ifdef` require the e-TeX extensions.  But not to fear; your TeX engine probably uses them.  If not, there are workarounds.

**EDIT** Fixed to handle @Caramdir's observation.  Now `\thispagestyle` expands to something which evaluates to the string input to `\pagestyle` or `\thispagestyle`.  Testing against that string is going to be harder because you have to expand one more step.

Comment: Wouldn't this give the wrong page style, when tested on the page after a `\thispagestyle`? This means a `\chapter` would set `\thepagestyle` to plain.

Comment: @Caramdir -- you are right! I tested it in a minimal example. But your idea, Matthew, is the same I meintioned.

Comment: @Caramdir: I guess you're right.  There's nothing to set it back after ‘this page’.  `\begin{think}`

Comment: `\end{think}` @Caramdir I sort of fixed it.

Comment: that's a full solution. It works nice with `\ifthenelse`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Only a test for the empty pagestyle is easy:

```
\makeatletter
\ifx\@evenfoot\@empty empty \else not empty\fi
\makeatother
```

Comment: I tried this out, but it didn't work. \documentclass{memoir} \begin{document} \pagestyle{empty} \makeatletter \ifx\@evenfoot\@empty empty \else not empty\fi \makeatother \end{document}

it said "not empty"

Comment: @Daniel: I suppose that memoir has another definition of the pagestyles. I'll have a look

Comment: @Daniel memoir redefines `\evenfoot`